# when delete treeview row of python tkinter, how can i make in order number in treeview column

Tags: python, tkinter, indexing, treeview

it is the problem i faced

i make treeview, with function of insert and delete

insert is act well, but delete is not.

i want to modify the number of no. when i delete treeview row

i make it in order as 1,2,3,4,5,6

please help me

[image]

[image]

please help me

pin_position_tree.index(selected_position) other method

Comment: Just go through all the rows and update the number in the "No." column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `no.` column is the first column in your Treeview, you can update the numbering of your rows with the following code

```
my_treeview = ttk.Treeview()  # Replace this with your own treeview...
for i, item in enumerate(my_treeview.get_children(''), 1):
    my_treeview.set(item, 0, i)
```

Comment: i really appreciate for it